# Dplyr rowwise access entire column

Tags: r, dplyr

Given the following data

```
   A B
1  1 2
2  2 2
3  3 3
4  4 4
5  5 4
```

For each row I'd like to find the index where A exceeds B for the first time.
So the required answer is:

```
  A B NextIndex
1 1 2         3
2 2 2         3
3 3 3         4
4 4 4         5
5 5 5         5
```

My approach with `dplyr` is

```
A_col<-foo$A  
foo  %>%  rowwise() %>% mutate(NextIndex=which(A_col-B>0)[1] )
```

My actual data.frame is several million rows and the processing time increases dramatically. Note, I reference the full `A_col` in each row comparison and I tried a version using `row_number()` but didn't achieve a significant speed improvement. 
Also, note, A and B are actually `POSIXct` variables in my data.frame and will be strictly increasing in time but not by periodic amounts.

How would I improve the efficiency of this expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `vapply`

```
foo$nextIndex <- vapply(foo$B, function(x) which(foo$A-x>0)[1], 1)
foo
#   A B nextIndex
#1 1 2         3
#2 2 2         3
#3 3 3         4
#4 4 4         5
#5 5 4         5
```

Or another option if the values are in order

```
findInterval(foo$B, foo$A)+1L
#[1] 3 3 4 5 5
```

Using it in the `dplyr` chain

```
foo %>% 
    mutate(rowIndex = findInterval(B, A)+1L)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
df$nextIndex <- apply(df, 1, function(x) which.max(df$A - x[2] > 0))
df
  A B nextIndex
1 1 2         3
2 2 2         3
3 3 3         4
4 4 4         5
5 5 4         5
```